# Add web control to master page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to upgrade a SharePoint site from 2010 to the 2013 version.

I had a web control in my master page that I really can't get to work in sharepoint 2013.

I have built the web control in a class file and deployed the dll to the web application so it appears in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\bin

I have then edited the default master page adding at the top of the page.

`<!--SPM:<%@ Register TagPrefix="Gnie" Namespace="GNIE.SharePoint.Core.Branding"Assembly="GNIE.SharePoint.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aad712380eccafda" %>-->`

I have added the control to the master page as so

`<div>
                               <!--SPM:<Gnie:TaxonomyNavigationControl ID="taxnav" ListName="Documents" FieldName="Technical Document Type"  runat="server" />-->
                            </div>`

The Web control code is quite standard

```
namespace GNIE.SharePoint.Core.Branding

{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]

[ToolboxData("<{0}:TaxonomyNavigationControl runat=server></{0}:TaxonomyNavigationControl>")]

public class TaxonomyNavigationControl : WebControl

/*code here */

}`
```

When I try to view the page in sharepoint I get error saying Unknown server tag 'Gnie:TaxonomyNavigationControl'

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
<!--SPM:<Gnie:TaxonomyNavigationControl ID="taxnav" ListName="Documents" FieldName="Technical Document Type" runat="server" />-->
```

With:

```
<!--MS:<Gnie:TaxonomyNavigationControl ID="taxnav" ListName="Documents" FieldName="Technical Document Type" runat="server" >-->
<!--ME:<Gnie:TaxonomyNavigationControl>-->
```